# Can node.js let a Web browser (client) get access to any directory in my computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver, httpserver

Just to let you know I'm very new to setting up a Web server and I'm questioning to organize my input. I set up http-server implementing Node.js script below:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World and Youaaaa.');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

- I guess this code set up a http-server on my computer and let the port 3000 of the http-server open to the Internet. Does that mean the Internet can get access to any directory in my computer from C drive to Desktop?
- Which directory in my computer does this url `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` indicate ? If I add to this some words like `C:/UserName/Desktop/sample.js` and set it on Web Browser's URL form , can the Web browser implement `sample.js` file?

Comment: In most cases using the `http` module directly is more work then it is worth and you'd be better off using something like `express` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about express. I would try.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess this code set up a http-server on my computer and let the port 3000 of the http-server open to the Internet. Does that mean the Internet can get access to any directory in my computer from C drive to Desktop?

No.

You haven't written any code which lets your Node.js program read a file. Let alone a file determined by user input.

> Which directory in my computer does this url http://127.0.0.1:3000/ indicate ?

No directory.

Look at your code:

> ```
>   res.end('Hello World and Youaaaa.');
> ```

That's a hard coded string, not a reference to any file.

> If I add to this some words like C:/UserName/Desktop/sample.js and set it on Web Browser's URL form , can the Web browser implement sample.js file?

No.